# Convert SoftwareBitmap to Mat for C#

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, winui-3

I have a `SoftwareBitmap` object which I need to process using openCV. I haven't found code for C# to convert `SoftwareBitmap` to `Mat`. I tried to use C++ version but I don't have much experience in C++ and I had some issues converting the code. Is there version for C#?

Comment: Do you want to convert Bitmap to Mat or SoftwareBitmap to Mat?

Comment: does C# give you plain data in memory? then you can wrap that into a cv::Mat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of playing with all these stuff. I've come with the solution. The only thing I don't like about it that it must be executed on the UI thread (sorry if it called different in WinUI 3).

```
public static Mat ToMat(SoftwareBitmap source)
{
    var writable = new WriteableBitmap(source.PixelWidth, source.PixelHeight);
    source.CopyToBuffer(writable.PixelBuffer);

    var buffer = writable.PixelBuffer;
    using var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
    var bytes = new byte[buffer.Length];
    reader.ReadBytes(bytes);

    var mat = new Mat(source.PixelHeight, source.PixelWidth, DepthType.Cv8U, 4);
    mat.SetTo(bytes);

    return mat;
}
```

I'm executing this code in the behavior so I run it like this. I'm getting an exception if I run the code in a thread from the thread pool.
`The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.`

```
this.DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(DispatcherQueuePriority.Normal,
() => mat =  ToMat(softwareBitmap));
```

**Updated**
One more way to do it is to use [Emgu.CV.Bitmap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Emgu.CV.Bitmap/) library to convert Mat into Bitmap object

```
var mat = mat.ToBitmap();
```

After that Bitmap can be converted into `SoftwareBitmap` or can be used directly in the app. `Bitmap` can be showed on the WinUI3 `Image` control.

Answer (score 1):

as one of possible solution - you can link needed C++ written library to your C# project.

Comment: Yeah, it should work. Thanks, it will be my backup plan :)